# Calling "transferFrom" from contract

Tags: solidity, remix, transferfrom

Solidity noob but have looked around and cannot seem to find an answer to my specific issue.  I am sure I am overlooking something really obvious but need help.

I am working in Remix using the Injected Web3 environment.  I have successfully deployed a test contract from the injected wallet (using https://github.com/OpenZeppelin/openzeppelin-contracts/blob/master/contracts/token/ERC20/ERC20.sol) and I can see the 1 trillion tokens in that wallet.  So far so good.

I have a second contract and am just trying to set up some functions so I can:

- Approve an allowance for the contract to spend this token on my behalf
- Send the token on my behalf (to itself, in this case)

The code I have is:

```
    
    // grant allowance to contract to spend 'amount' on behalf of caller
    function approveToken(uint amount) public payable {
        token.increaseAllowance(address(this), amount);
    }
    
    // send 'amount' from caller to contract
    function sendToken(uint amount) public payable {
        token.transferFrom(msg.sender, address(this), amount);
    }
    
    // return balance of 'token' owned by caller
    function getTokenBalance() public view returns(uint256) {
        return token.balanceOf(msg.sender);
    } 
    
    // return 'token' allowance contract can spend on behalf of caller
    function getTokenAllowance() public view returns(uint256) {
        return token.allowance(msg.sender, address(this));
    }
```

`approveToken` executes without any error

`getTokenBalance` works fine (shows the tokens)

`getTokenAllowance` returns 0

What I think is happening is when I run the `sendToken` function from remix my wallet is the caller, not the contract.  So I am essentially checking whether I have given myself an allowance to send this token, and perhaps that is what is tripping things up.  So it seems to me I need to make sure the contract is what is calling the `sendToken` function as that is the 3rd party given an allowance.

But I am lost, any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Sorted, was being stupid and calling the tokens approve() function via the transfer contract and not on on the token contract directly.